# Javascript how create an element with attributes with web components

Tags: javascript, web-component

I want to create an element on the fly with attributes, NOT add them after the object is already created (setAttribute does not work).

Point: I have setup a web component to interact with it's attributes inside it's constructor (this.getAttribute).  If you create an element on the fly (document.createElement) the attributes are empty.  Setting them afterwards won't work.

note: I know I can get the funcality I need in another way, this would just create the most user friendly version of the web component (minimal code).

```
class List extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(temp) {
        super();
             if(this.getAttribute('att')!=null){
                 do stuff
             }
     }
 }
```

other code

```
document.createElement('list')
```

Comment: What attributes do you want the element to have? Should there be a default value, what should it be? How should it be over-written by a user-set attribute-value?

Comment: I do know a bit about Web Components, and ``document.createElement('list')`` can never create a valid Web Component. Please provide  a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't have access to attributes from within the constructor. You will need to use the connectedCallback() function for that.  Can you provide that update for Danny? how is it that you would like to define your element and what attributes are you using?

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick sample showing how to reference and set attributes within a web-component class definition.
You can't reference attributes from the constructor, I think this is actually a static method, not an instance method.

connectedCallback() and likely? adoptedCallback will allow interaction with the element Object.

This demonstrates testing for an attribute, setting an attribute and value, and getting a value.
I use dataset https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset cause that is where custom values ideally should go.

```js
class UIInput extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // will cause issue if un commented
    console.log(`'data-testing' value is ${this.dataset.testing}`);
  };

  connectedCallback() {
    // empty signature
    // test for attribute
    if (!this.dataset.testing) {
      console.log(`'data-testing' attribute absent`);
      //print the element
      console.log(this);
      return;
    }
    // set / assign an attribute value
    this.dataset.connected = true;
    console.log(`'data-testing' value is ${this.dataset.testing} and 'connected' is ${this.dataset.connected}`);
    // print the element
    console.log(this);

  };
};
customElements.define('ui-input', UIInput);
```

```html
<ui-input id="empty">Empty!</ui-input>
<br/>
<ui-input id="supplied" data-testing="Value Supplied">Value Supplied</ui-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a playground showing when and when not **attributes** are available in the `constructor`

https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/cxntaodk/

Run the code, explain for yourself what the `console` shows

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
  class BaseClass extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      console.log(this.nodeName, this.id||"NO ID", "constructor");
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = this.id;
    }
  }
  customElements.define("component-a", class extends BaseClass {});
  container.innerHTML += `<component-a id="1"></component-a><component-b id="2">Hello! Web Component</component-b>`;
</script>
<component-a id="3"></component-a><component-b id="4"></component-b>
<script>
  customElements.define("component-b", class extends BaseClass {});
  container.innerHTML += `<component-a id="5"></component-a><component-b id="6">Hello! Web Component</component-b>`;
  const element = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
  document.body.append(
    element("component-a", {
      id: "7"
    }),
    element("component-b", {
      id: "8"
    })
  );
</script>
```

- the `constructor` only has access to **attributes** ***WHEN THE DOM WAS PARSED***
- setting `innerHTML` causes a DOM parse and sets **all attributes** (which I think OP is asking)
- `createElement` only runs the **constructor**, does not parse DOM
  That is why the general advice is to not access attributes/DOM in the `constructor`